# How do I separate PyQT5 logic class from QtDesign class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making a graphical application in PyQT5, and have used the QtDesigner for the UI design. I have converted the UI file into Python, and now have a class containing all the UI-related code.

A while back I was told I should keep the logic (what happens when you press a certain button, etc.) in a separate class to the UI class. I was just wondering how I'd do this? What would the if **name** == "**main**" look like? My apologies, I'm new to PyQT.

Thanks.

Comment: why not keep your ui in .ui file and load it during window creation? it's better than using 2 classes, one for ui and second for logic

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've never taken that approach. I'd just like to know how to do it with multiple classes, as that was what was recommended to me a while back. Thanks again.

Comment: @Poots. The section [Using Qt Designer](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) in the PyQt5 docs has several examples showing how to use the code created by pyuic. The 2nd and 3rd examples are the best ones to use.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll be sure to take a look over that. When you refer to the 'examples', you refer to the snippets of code beneath the header 'Using the Generated Code'?

Comment: @Poots. Yes - read through that whole section. And for some slightly more complete examples, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41968112/984421).